# Error deploying flask app on pythonanywhere

Tags: python, flask, pythonanywhere

I'm trying to deploy my web application on pythonanywhere but I'm running into this error and I don't know what to do about it.

```
2023-08-23 06:02:00,291: Error running WSGI application
2023-08-23 06:02:00,294: ImportError: cannot import name 'app' from 'flaskapp2023summer' (unknown location)
2023-08-23 06:02:00,294:   File "/var/www/cgmiao_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 83, in <module>
2023-08-23 06:02:00,294:     from flaskapp2023summer import app as application  # noqa
```

my wsgi.py file has this as the import:

```
import sys
#
## The "/home/cgmiao" below specifies your home
## directory -- the rest should be the directory you uploaded your Flask
## code to underneath the home directory.  So if you just ran
## "git clone git@github.com/myusername/myproject.git"
## ...or uploaded files to the directory "myproject", then you should
## specify "/home/cgmiao/myproject"
path = '/home/cgmiao/flaskapp2023summer'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)
#
from backend import app as application  # noqa
```

with everything else commented out. And my file path looks like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BmVk.png)

My backend.py file looks like this at the beginning

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, url_for, redirect, flash, session
from forms import RegistrationForm, LoginForm, SearchForm, DeleteAccountForm
import pymysql


app = Flask(__name__)
```

Can someone please  help me figure out my problem or if someone had the same problem, would they mind sharing what fixed it for them?
Thank you

I've tried changing the path of my files in the wsgi.py file but can't seem to get rid of this error.

Comment: See the help page on how Python looks for the modules that you are trying to import: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingImportError/